# Is there a simple way to understand why $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}=S^1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is there a simple way to understand why $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}=S^1$? I heard about it in one of Wildberger's lectures on algebraic topology but did not understand his arguments on the cosets.

Comment: That it is not possible. Think about cardinality.

Comment: Hi. Check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKvbGFrkx18

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} = S^1$, which is true? (I cannot watch the video right now, but $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \neq S^1$, by cardinality reasons for example like Yotas Trejos says).

Comment: For reference, Wildberger is an (ultra)finist who doesn't believe in the reals. He works over the rationals.

Comment: @trb456 anyone who doesn't believe in the reals shouldn't believe in $S^1$ either

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group#Group_structure). $\mathbf{R/Z}=S^1$ is true because you can define an isomorphism via $f(x+\mathbf{Z})=e^{2\pi i\times x}$.

Comment: @trb456 What does he call $S^1$ then? I just assumed it was the standard circle.

Comment: @trb456 what does it mean that Wildberger is an (ultra)finist who doesn't believe in the reals? (I don't have a pure math background)

Comment: @Marion It's a complex topic, you can [read the Wikipedia page about finitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitism) for example. It's a (very) nonstandard framework for mathematics.

Comment: @Marion: It's going to be hard to explain without a decent math background. Roughly speaking, finitists believe that working with infinite objects *as* infinite objects is problematic. Ultrafinists believe that no infinite objects exist at all, because they cannot actually be "constructed". You need to understand that Wildberger practices an extreme brand of constructivism that is not at all universally embraced within mathematics. So AdLibitum's comment is exactly right: Wildberger shouldn't believe in the 1-sphere, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exponential map
$$
r\mapsto e^{2\pi ir}=\cos(2\pi r)+i\sin(2\pi r)
$$
is a homomorphism of groups $\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb C^\times$ that realizes (via Isomorphism Theorem) the isomorphism
$$
\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\stackrel\sim\longrightarrow S^1.
$$
Note that under this isomorphism the quotient $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ (which is naturally a subgroup of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$) is identified with the group $\mu_\infty$ of all roots of $1$ in $\Bbb C$ (which is a subgroup of $S^1$)

---

From a topological point of view, taking the quotient $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ means to identify points in $\Bbb R$ whose distance between them is an integer. Thus the quotient is represented by the segment $[0,1]$ with $0\equiv1$ the only identification.

It takes a few seconds to visualize that as a closed path, which is what $S^1$ is, topologically.

Comment: I'm not sure your answer is useful considering the context (finitism, $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't exist...)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: well, I think I said something about $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ as well.

Comment: The problem is that I don't think Wildberger's $S^1$ is the standard $S^1$... I hardly know anything about (ultra)finitism, but I wouldn't even be surprised if the exponential function didn't exist in that setting! I'm not even sure it would make sense to talk about it.